# React: How to access file that gets passed in to html input type=file

Tags: html, reactjs, file, input, file-upload

If I have something like
`<input type='file' onChange={function}>`
How can I access the file that eventually gets passed in?

So I could do something like this:

```
const function = () =>{
listOfFiles.add(file)
}
```

I would like to retrieve whatever files are passed to the input/file uploader and add them to a list. But I am not sure how to access the actual file that a user uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: (removed setIsSelected(true);, its not needed)
I think you can use react states, it will make your life easier.
Try this one:

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
const changeHandler = (event) => {
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);

    };
<input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
```

Your file will be in the **selectedFile** variable.

Comment: what is `setIsSelected`? It would be undefined

Comment: Oh sorry, i had there other state, forget obout the setIsSelected(true); its not needed